# Explode two keys in PySpark/SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the source data as shown below:

```json
{
 id: 1,
 y: [
     {"firstName": "Will", "lastName": "Jackson"}, 
     {"firstName": "Chris", "lastName": "Johnson"}
    ],
 z: [
     {"profession": "Actor"},
     {"profession": "Comedian", "flag": "True"},
     {"profession": "Fighter", "flag": "False"}
    ]
},
{
...
}
```

Is there a way I can explode the `y` & `z` columns in the JSON that contains JSON objects within the array. Also, I want to conditionally read the `profession` column based on `flag`. The `flag` could be a key that's present or absent. If absent or `False`, read the `profession` as NULL. If present read the value. Ultimately, the above JSON should be as shown below:

| id | firstName | lastName | profession | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Will | Jackson | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | Chris | Johnson | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | Will | Jackson | Comedian | True |
| 1 | Chris | Johnson | Comedian | True |
| 1 | Will | Jackson | NULL | False |
| 1 | Chris | Johnson | NULL | False |

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType,ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode,arrays_zip,col,when


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pyspark-by-examples').getOrCreate()

simple_json = """{"id": 1, "y": [ {"firstName": "Will", "lastName": "Jackson"},  {"firstName": "Chris", "lastName": "Johnson"} ],"z": [{"profession": "Actor"},{"profession": "Comedian", "flag": "True"},{"profession": "Fighter", "flag": "False"}]}"""

json_schema = StructType(fields=[
    StructField('id', StringType()),
    StructField('y', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('firstName', StringType()),StructField('lastName', StringType())]))),
    StructField('z', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('flag', StringType()),StructField('profession', StringType())])))])

rddjson = sc.parallelize([simple_json])
df = sqlContext.read.json(rddjson)
newDF = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema=json_schema)
df3 = newDF.select(newDF.id,newDF.y,newDF.z).withColumn("name",explode(arrays_zip(newDF.y))).withColumn("profession_orig",explode(arrays_zip(newDF.z))).withColumn("profession", when(col("profession_orig.z.flag") == "True",col("profession_orig.z.profession")).otherwise("NULL")).select("id","name.y.firstName","name.y.lastName","profession","profession_orig.z.flag")
df3.show()
```

output -

```
+---+---------+--------+----------+-----+
| id|firstName|lastName|profession| flag|
+---+---------+--------+----------+-----+
|  1|     Will| Jackson|      NULL| null|
|  1|     Will| Jackson|  Comedian| True|
|  1|     Will| Jackson|      NULL|False|
|  1|    Chris| Johnson|      NULL| null|
|  1|    Chris| Johnson|  Comedian| True|
|  1|    Chris| Johnson|      NULL|False|
+---+---------+--------+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score -1):

Just following your logic: explode then transform `flag` and `profession` as you want

```py
(df
    .withColumn('y', F.explode('y'))
    .withColumn('z', F.explode('z'))
    .select('id', 'y.*', 'z.*')
    .withColumn('profession', F
        .when((F.col('flag').isNull()) | (F.col('flag') == False), None)
        .otherwise(F.col('profession'))
    )
    .show(10, False)
)

+---+---------+--------+-----+----------+
|id |firstName|lastName|flag |profession|
+---+---------+--------+-----+----------+
|1  |Will     |Jackson |null |null      |
|1  |Will     |Jackson |True |Comedian  |
|1  |Will     |Jackson |False|null      |
|1  |Chris    |Johnson |null |null      |
|1  |Chris    |Johnson |True |Comedian  |
|1  |Chris    |Johnson |False|null      |
+---+---------+--------+-----+----------+
```